# Odoo 14 return product image for xml-rpc call

Tags: image, odoo, xml-rpc

want to return product data to xml-rpc call from php, i can return other fields from product.template but i think odoo stores images in different way, please help how i can get and return images stored in Odoo db to php call through xml-rpc?

my .php file:

```
<?php
// following code running successfully to connect & get data from Odoo database running in VM
// Login information
$url = 'http://192.168.18.71:8069';
$url_auth = $url . '/xmlrpc/2/common';
$url_exec = $url . '/xmlrpc/2/object';
$db = 'odb';
$username = 'odoouser@myhost.com';
$password = 'admin';
require_once('ripcord\ripcord.php');
// Login
$common = ripcord::client($url_auth);
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());
$models = ripcord::client($url_exec);
$models                 // The (Ripcord) client
    ->execute_kw(       // Execute command
    'table.reference',  // Referenced model, e.g. 'res.partner' or 'account.invoice'
    'search',           // Search method of the referenced model
    array()             // Search domain
);
$result = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
               'product.template', 'search_read',
               array(array(array('active', '=', true))),
               array('fields'=>array('id', 'name', 'list_price'), 'limit'=>10));
          //var_dump($result);
foreach ($result as $results) {
     print("{$results['id']} {$results['name']} {$results['list_price']}<br/>");
}
?>
```

regards

Comment: Just "read" the binary field for example `image` and you should get a base64 encoded image in the xml-rpc result/return.

Comment: thanks @CZoellner i failed to find this binary field in "product.template" and "product_product" so, i came here to ask where it stores and how i can get to return with other fields in a xml-rpc call which is from php.

Comment: FYI `product.product` also known as "variant" has [these image fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9864fb6a159f5f145421b4e51b6125e25a69e7c9/addons/product/models/product.py#L127-L145) and `product.template` also known as "template" is using the image mixin so has [these image fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9864fb6a159f5f145421b4e51b6125e25a69e7c9/odoo/addons/base/models/image_mixin.py).

Comment: thankful for these information, i don't know about these.  but please check my php code above, i have to consult with a real php developer? or you can help me? as i did efforts myself to have a running php code (off course with the help of internet search) but don't know how to's...

Comment: i'm not very fit with php sorry :-(

Comment: ok, thanks for your interest to guide/help me :)

Comment: You can add `'image_128'` to the fields list then use `$results['image_128']` to get the field value.